Librosa Split cannot separate audio
I am trying to create a filter to separate relevant audio from silence. I have been following the directions listed in this post: Find the best decibel threshold to split an audio into segments with and without human voice in Python.
I have recorded a file with noise and ambient silence. I am trying to use the librosa.effects.split function to separate out the audio. My expectation was that I could determine a max dB value of the silence and threshold at that value but I am not having luck.
Here is my code:
Visualizing the audio files:
`
y, sr_noise = librosa.load(noise, sr=16000)
S_noise = np.abs(librosa.stft(y))

y, sr_silence = librosa.load(silence, sr=16000)
S_silence = np.abs(librosa.stft(y))

import librosa
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, sharex=True, sharey=True)
imgpow = librosa.display.specshow(librosa.power_to_db(S_noise**2, ref=np.max),
                              sr=sr_noise, y_axis='log', x_axis='time',
                              ax=ax[0])
ax[0].set(title='Noise Log-Power spectrogram (max)')
ax[0].label_outer()
imgdb1 = librosa.display.specshow(librosa.power_to_db(S_silence**2, ref=np.max),
                              sr=sr_silence, y_axis='log', x_axis='time', 
                              ax=ax[1])
ax[1].set(title='Silence Log-Power spectrogram (max)')

fig.colorbar(imgpow, ax=ax[0], format="%+2.0f dB")
fig.colorbar(imgdb1, ax=ax[1], format="%+2.0f dB")

Decibel values of audio files
Determining top_db value:
db_noise = core.power_to_db(S_noise**2, ref=np.max, top_db=None)
db_silence = core.power_to_db(S_silence**2, ref=np.max, top_db=None)
print(np.min(db_noise), np.max(db_noise))  #-136.57549 -3.8146973e-06
print(np.min(db_silence), np.max(db_silence))  #-111.44477 -9.536743e-07

Applying threshold:
top_db = -5  # selected manually because it is about half way between np.max(db_noise) and np.max(db_silence)
print(librosa.effects.split(S_noise, top_db=top_db))  # []
print(librosa.effects.split(S_silence, top_db=top_db))  #[]

I tried the above code and several variations but I'm out of ideas. Clearly there is some technical understanding I have missed.

You probably already guessed it but the threshold (top_db) should be a positive number. top_db > 0 is the threshold (in decibels) below reference to consider as silence.
By default, it uses the maximum intensity of the signal as the reference level but this can be changed (see the doc).
